# pandas apply 2 different functions for particular range of rows of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using Pandas DataFrame to extract a file and apply transformation to some columns. Here I want to call/use different function named func2 for every 5-10 row.

```
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', dtype=str)
csv_input = input_df
csv_input['acct1'] = input_df['acct1'].apply(lambda x: func1(x)[1])
csv_input.to_csv('input.csv', index=False)
```

I'm trying to use for loop and use i%5 but its not giving the expected result, any suggestions please?

Comment: Provide [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just edited the question to give the complete picture, basically I'm just transforming the 1st column of the input file, now I'm trying to call different functions for every 5-10 rows from the file..

Comment: so you want to apply `func1` for 0-4, 10-14 ... rows and apply func2 for 5-9, 15-19 ... rowS?

Comment: yea Nihal, thats correct!

Comment: thats easy if you create 2 list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
length = len(input_df)

list1 = [j for i in range(0, length, 10) for j in range(i, length if i + 5 >= length else i + 5)]
list2 = list(set(range(0, length)) - set(list1))

print(list1)
print(list2)

input_df.loc[list1, 'acct1'] = input_df.loc[list1, 'acct1'].apply(lambda x: func1(x)[1])
input_df.loc[list2, 'acct1'] = input_df.loc[list2, 'acct1'].apply(lambda x: func2(x)[1])
```

for example if my length is 82 then output will be

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 80, 81]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]
```